# GCP Monitoring Alert Notification Channel (Web Hook) with MS Teams

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks, microsoft-teams, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to use Teams webhooks in a GCP monitoring notification channel. The webhook URL was created by viewing the guide below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-connectors

But there seems to be no action in the test connection. Can't I use the GCP Monitoring notification channel in Teams by linking it with a webhook?

Comment: Could you please try to create the Webhook by following this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?WT.mc_id=m365-12509-rwilliams) and use Postman to send the request?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT 
Thanks for your reply.

If you look at the docs and send messages such as POST using postman, you will receive Teams normally.
However, after registering a webhook on GCP, creating a Test Alert and trying it, no alarm is coming from Teams.

Could you please let me know if there is another way to connect?
sincerely
Gyeongsik Jang

Comment: do you mind showing what payload are you sending ? also, please check the doc for webhooks on GCP https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#webhooks

Comment: @c69;
@Prasad-MSFT
Thanks for your reply.

By referring to the link below, I solved the method of linking StackDriver and Teams through Cloud Function.
https://github.com/Courtsite/gcp-monitoring-to-teams

Comment: Ok thanks. If it resolved your issue, could you please add detailed explanation in answer section for better visibility

Comment: seems like the problem was about adding token to the url, could you please confirm ? @GyeongSikJang

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Please refer to the topic as it has been visualized and answered in the corresponding topic.

Comment: @c69 Can I add an Auth_Token value when creating a webhook in Teams?
If possible, could you please describe how to do it in your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone the source from the github link and import it.

```
git clone https://github.com/JangGyeongSik/gcp-teams-monitoring.git
```

After that, create a Teams Webhook through the attached link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?WT.mc_id=m365-12509-rwilliams

Edit the .env.yaml File as follows.
TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL is the previously issued URL.
AUTH_TOKEN specifies an arbitrary value.

```
TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL: [TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL]
AUTH_TOKEN: gyeongsik_jang
```

Then, deploy the Cloud Function through the ShellFile below.

In the case of Service Account, you must be granted the following permissions in advance.

- Monitoring Metrics Writer, Logs Writer

```
gcloud functions deploy gcp-monitoring-teams-trigger \
    --entry-point=F \
    --memory=128MB \
    --region=asia-northeast3 \
    --runtime=go113 \
    --env-vars-file=env.yaml \
    --trigger-http \
    --timeout=10s \
    --service-account=[SERVICE_ACCOUNT]
```

Create the generated Trigger URL as Monitoring Notification Channel as shown below.

Auth_Token value should be entered at the end of the URL.

```
https://[Cloud_Function_Trigger_URL]?auth_token=gyeongsik_jang
```

With this setup, you can check the Test Connection in Teams as follows.
[image]

Thank you for reading the long post.

Gyeongsik Jang

Answer (score 0):

I have created a GitHub repo taking the code from https://github.com/Courtsite/gcp-monitoring-to-teams.git and I modified to be able to use internally with pubsub notifications to a topic and then post it to the web hook of MS Teams, with this you don't have to expose the cloud function or break some org policy.

https://github.com/foward/gcp-monitoring-to-msteams

I hope this helps...

Regards